# Open file for reading and executing (but not writing)

Tags: node.js, fs

I am looking at `fs.open()` here:

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_open_path_flags_mode_callback

I want to open a file for both reading and executing.

it gives these flags:

> 'r' - Open file for reading. An exception occurs if the file does not
>   exist.
>
> 'r+' - Open file for reading and writing. An exception occurs if the
>   file does not exist.
>
> 'rs+' - Open file for reading and writing in synchronous mode.
>   Instructs the operating system to bypass the local file system cache.
>
> This is primarily useful for opening files on NFS mounts as it allows
>   skipping the potentially stale local cache. It has a very real impact
>   on I/O performance so using this flag is not recommended unless it is
>   needed.
>
> Note that this doesn't turn fs.open() into a synchronous blocking
>   call. If synchronous operation is desired fs.openSync() should be
>   used.
>
> 'w' - Open file for writing. The file is created (if it does not
>   exist) or truncated (if it exists).
>
> 'wx' - Like 'w' but fails if path exists.
>
> 'w+' - Open file for reading and writing. The file is created (if it
>   does not exist) or truncated (if it exists).
>
> 'wx+' - Like 'w+' but fails if path exists.
>
> 'a' - Open file for appending. The file is created if it does not
>   exist.
>
> 'ax' - Like 'a' but fails if path exists.
>
> 'a+' - Open file for reading and appending. The file is created if it
>   does not exist.
>
> 'ax+' - Like 'a+' but fails if path exists.

I am guessing opening for reading and executing would be `rx` but that's just a guess, anybody know for sure? There must be a reason it's not listed?

Comment: Yeah as I suspected, my "guess" was wrong - if I use a made-up flag called "rx" - I get this error - `Error: Unknown file open flag: rx`

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to execute from your file stream anyway, so there's no such thing as opening for reading and executing.  Executing is independent from this stream.

To execute, take a look at child_process and its various methods.

Comment: upvoted...ughh that's kinda lame, because now I have to make 2 parallel fs calls, one to check if it's readable another to check if it's executable, it would be nice to be able to do two in one?

Comment: @AlexanderMills What's the root problem you're working on?  Usually, you'd want to not check if something is readable or executable... you'd just try to read and execute and see if it worked.  The reason is that between the first check and the time you actually need to open or execute, the state may have changed.  On the other hand if you're just checking anyway, you can always do a directory listing for permissions... but that doesn't tell you much about the user your app is running under.

Comment: Yeah I agree that you want to avoid that race condition that you mention. Hmmm, the problem is that if I try to execute it directly, and the file has no hashbang, `/bin/sh` is invoked on the file, and it's nearly impossible to know at that point why the file failed to execute properly (if the file is not supposed to be interpreted by `sh`). In my case, it's safe to try to find out if the file is executable.